# How do I initialize an immutable Swift property to a computed value ?

Tags: swift

When I have this initializer:

```
let channels : [TVChannel]

required init?(json : NSObject)
{
    if let x = json as? [NSObject]
    {
        self.channels = x.map { TVChannel(json:$0)! }
    }
}
```

The compiler gives me the error:

> Error:(12, 14) constant 'self.channels' used before being initialized

Why is this ? And how do I initialize the property my mapped array of `TVChannel`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler needs to know how to initialize `self.channels` when the control flow doesn't enter the `if let` condition.

A solution could be to provide an else branch:

```
if let x = json as? [NSObject] {
    self.channels = x.map { TVChannel(json:$0)! }
} else {
    self.channels = []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle both cases where `json` is and isn't an array of NSObjects. Alternatively you could define a default value to the property and make it a `var`

e.g.

```
required init?(json : NSObject) {

  if let x = json as? [NSObject] {
    channels = x.map { TVChannel(json: $0) }
  } else {
    channels = [ ]
  }

}
```

or

```
var channels: [TVChannel] = [ ]
```

or

```
var channels = [TVChannel]()
```